# Error .NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TableLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, programación-móvil

Estoy intentando crear una tabla dinamica en Android studio, segui un tutorial y en este funciona bien a mi me sale este error y lo segui paso por paso adjunto mi archivo y mi error, me sale como si estuviera apuntando a null pero como digo en el video funciona bien.
Adjunto link del tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSafkhA6TZA.

DONDE CREO LA TABLA :

```js
   

public class TableDynamic {
    private TableLayout tableLayout;
    private Context context;
    private String[]header;
    private ArrayList<String[]>data;
    private TableRow tableRow;
    private TextView txtCell;
    private int indexC;
    private int indexR;
    public TableDynamic(TableLayout tableLayout, Context context) {
        this.tableLayout=tableLayout;
        this.context=context;
    }
    public void addHeader(String[]header){
        this.header=header;
    createHeader();
    }
    public void addData(ArrayList<String[]>data){
this.data=data;
createDataTable();
    }
    private void newRow(){
        tableRow=new TableRow(context);
    }
    private void newCell(){
      txtCell=new TextView(context);
      txtCell.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
      txtCell.setTextSize(25);

    }
    private void createHeader(){
indexC=0;
newRow();
while (indexC<header.length){
    newCell();
    txtCell.setText(header[indexC++]);
    tableRow.addView(txtCell,newTableRowParams());

}
 tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
    private void createDataTable(){
        String info;
        for(indexR=1;indexR<=header.length;indexR++){
newRow();
            for(indexC=0;indexC<header.length;indexC++){
                newCell();
                String[] colums=data.get(indexR-1);
                info=(indexC<colums.length)?colums[indexC]:"";
                txtCell.setText(info);
                tableRow.addView(txtCell,newTableRowParams());

            }
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
        }
    }
    private TableRow.LayoutParams newTableRowParams(){
        TableRow.LayoutParams params= new TableRow.LayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(1,1,1,1);
        params.weight=1;
        return params;
    }

}
```

MI ACTIVITY donde llamo la tabla

```js
public class Historial extends Activity {
private String[]header={"Producto","Cantidad","Fecha"};
private ArrayList<String[]>rows=new ArrayList<>();
    private TableLayout tableLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_historial);
        tableLayout=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
        TableDynamic tableDynamic=new TableDynamic(tableLayout,getApplicationContext());
        tableDynamic.addHeader(header);
        tableDynamic.addData(getclients());
    }
    private ArrayList<String[]>getclients(){
rows.add(new String[]{"1","Hola","Yes"});
        rows.add(new String[]{"2","H544a","es"});
        rows.add(new String[]{"3","H43546a","Ys"});
        rows.add(new String[]{"4","H5la","Ye"});
        return rows;

    }
}
```

Aqui es donde me dice el error que apunta a null

```js
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mauro.smart_orders, PID: 31327
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mauro.smart_orders/com.example.mauro.smart_orders.Historial}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TableLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3121)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:81)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1935)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7116)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TableLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.mauro.smart_orders.TableDynamic.createHeader(TableDynamic.java:50)
        at com.example.mauro.smart_orders.TableDynamic.addHeader(TableDynamic.java:26)
        at com.example.mauro.smart_orders.Historial.onCreate(Historial.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7698)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7687)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3096)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:81) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
```

Porfavor si alguien me puede decir cual es mi error o por que apunta a null

Answer (score 1):

En tu clase `TableDynamic` dentro de su constructor, puedes llamar el método `newRow()`

```
public TableDynamic(TableLayout tableLayout, Context context) {
        this.tableLayout=tableLayout;
        this.context=context;
        newRow();
    }
```

Para de esta forma inicializar la variable `tableRow` y evitar llamar un método de esta instancia con valor null.